# Missing data roughly proportional to the clusters, does this indicate MAR?

Tags: r, regression, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I have data in which the number of missing values per cluster (in this case, zip-code), are proportional to the population. Does this indicate Missing at Random (MAR)?

[image]
Third column with missing values are the variable which missingness is proportional to the cluster

[image]
X indicates missing values per cluster, Y indicates cluster sizes

[image]
regress missing values per cluster onto cluster sizes

Comment: what does MAR stand for?

Comment: missing at random

Comment: Please can you include your R code.